# Error running ArcHydro tools - can't set locations or arguments correctly?

Tags: arcpy, arc-hydro

I am working on trying to do some batch watershed processing.

I have watersheds created using ArcHydro, and was trying to run the Longest Flow Path tool in a batch method, on different feature classes (watershed polygons) located in a feature dataset in a geodatabase, using the code below:

```
# import stuff
import arcpy, os, traceback, sys, time
import ArcHydroTools


RasterLoc = "C:\Entire_State\Souhegan_River"
VectorLoc = "C:\Entire_State\Souhegan_River\Souhegan_River.gdb"
ArcHydroTools.SetTargetLocations("HydroConfig","Layers",RasterLoc,VectorLoc)
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace="C://Entire_State//Souhegan_River//Souhegan_River.gdb//Watersheds_Separate"
Flow_Dir_Grid = "C://Entire_State//Souhegan_River//Layers//fdr"

feat_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for feat in feat_classes:

    try:
        in_name = arcpy.env.workspace + "//" +  str(feat)
        out_name = arcpy.env.workspace + "//" +  str(feat) + "_LFP"
        ArcHydroTools.LongestFlowPath(in_name,Flow_Dir_Grid,out_name)


    except:
        name = feat + "_LFP"    # Just here to inspect errors

arcpy.AddMessage("Done generating LFPs.")
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

And I get this error:   "The default vector location () cannot be a directory. Modify the current geoprocessing workspace or set the Arc Hydro target locations. Failed to execute (LongestFlowPath)."

I don't really understand this error and how to fix it - would someone advise or provide an example of a working script that access this tool correctly?

**Edit:**  I have edited the script, to pursue a different path and got farther, with a different set of errors....This way it at least takes a while to fail, so it has me thinking it might be getting further along....?

Script:

```
# import stuff
import arcpy, os, traceback, sys, time
import ArcHydroTools


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput="TRUE"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

Flow_Dir_Grid = r"C:/Entire_State/Souhegan_River/Layers/fdr"

RasterLoc = "C:\Entire_State\Souhegan_River\Layers"
VectorLoc = "C:\Entire_State\Souhegan_River\Souhegan_River.gdb"
ArcHydroTools.SetTargetLocations("HydroConfig","Layers",RasterLoc,VectorLoc)


feature_class = r'C:\Entire_State\Souhegan_River\Souhegan_River.gdb\Watershed_Worked_ProjSP83'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature_class, "watersheds")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("watersheds", '*') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            id = row[3].encode('utf-8')
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("watersheds", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
            where_clause = """"{}" = {}""".format("HydroID", id)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("watersheds", "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)

            out_name = 'C:\Entire_State\Souhegan_River\Souhegan_River.gdb\Watersheds_Separate\\'+ str(row[3]) + "_LFP"

            ArcHydroTools.LongestFlowPath("watersheds",Flow_Dir_Grid,out_name)

        except:
            print ( "error for: " + str(row[3]) + "_LFP")


arcpy.AddMessage("Done generating LFPs.")
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

Error:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessorClass.Execute(String Name, IVariantArray ipValues, ITrackCancel pTrackCancel)
   at ESRI.APWR.ArcHydroGPTools.ApConfigGP.CreateFeatureClassGP(String path, String layerName, esriGeometryType geomType, String& exMessage, String templateName, String hasZ, String hasM, ISpatialReference spatialRef, Boolean addtoMap) in C:\Builds\HydroSolutions\10.5_ArcHydro\Sources\ArcHydroTools\src\ArcHydroGPTools\ApConfigGP.vb:line 4253
Failed to execute (LongestFlowPath).
```

"

Comment: Type r before RasterLoc and VectorLoc strings. ex: r"C:\Entire_State\Souhegan_River"

Comment: I don't think that is it, as advice that comes form one of the developers specified no use of 'r': https://community.esri.com/thread/85866